# Noob here, can somebody please explain this piece of code to me?

Tags: c++

```
struct TargetList_t
{
float Distance;
float AimbotAngle[3];

TargetList_t()
{

}

TargetList_t(float aimbotAngle[], float myCoords[], float enemyCoords[])
{
    Distance = Get3dDistance(myCoords[0], myCoords[1], myCoords[2], enemyCoords[0], enemyCoords[1], enemyCoords[2]);

    AimbotAngle[0] = aimbotAngle[0];
    AimbotAngle[1] = aimbotAngle[1];
    AimbotAngle[2] = aimbotAngle[2];
}

float Get3dDistance(float myCoordsX, float myCoordsZ, float myCoordsY, float eNx, float eNz, float eNy)
{
    return sqrt(
        pow(double(eNx - myCoordsX), 2.0) +
        pow(double(eNy - myCoordsY), 2.0) +
        pow(double(eNz - myCoordsZ), 2.0));
}
};
```

I believe it compares the distance between to entities? Would really appreciate a newbie friendly explanation.

Comment: It doesn't do much, stores some information about a target, list seems a bit misleading, maybe it's pushed to some container? Btw `sqrt` is not fast and you should avoid unless absolutely necessary ( which it's probably not here ).

Comment: That's what I figured.

Answer (score -2):

It's the Pythagorean theorem in three dimensions.

Comment: What makes you say "Also, it's not c++ but more likely c#.", could be either but the semi colon at the end of the struct definition is only necessary in c++ and use of struct in the op's code is not idiomatic c#.

Comment: My mistake, no idea why I thought that.